# trying to export java source code from an Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to export the source for a java object from an oracle database using the following code.

```
DECLARE
  blob1 BLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(blob1, FALSE);
  DBMS_JAVA.EXPORT_SOURCE('OBJECTNAME', 'SCHEMANAME', blob1);  
END;
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get this exception:

```
oracle.aurora.rdbms.ModifyPermissionException
```

even though I am running as System. Any ideas what is causing this and how I can get this to work.

Having investigated a bit more it worked when running as sysdba and also as the user that owns the objects. Unfortunately I am making a program to dump out the java objects in an Oracle database and I can't really force my users to be sysdba or the object's owner.

Is there any way I can stop this error?

Comment: You probably already tried granting execute, right?  I seem to recall having issues where system could not run procs because they had no exec privs.  Seems odd, but I know it happens once in a while.

Comment: I think so although it is entirly possible I have got it wrong. The thing is it seems to be executing DBMS_JAVA.EXPORT_SOURCE but is getting the exception part way through running the EXPORT_SOURCE proc.

Comment: If you did something like this, you probably got it right:
SQL> connect sys/password
SQL> grant execute on dbms_java to system;
SQL> connect system/password
SQL> @script  (run your script)

Comment: Well I did it again to be sure and it still doesn't work so I guess that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect use "as sysdba" option. I don't get ModifyPermissionException when I login as sysdba. See my actions below. The ORA-29532 I am getting is becuse I simply don;t have the Java class in my database. let me know if it worked for you.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\KrassimirB>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Mar 18 15:58:10 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys/oracle@orcl as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> @C:\tmp\java_export.sql
  7  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
java.sql.SQLException: no such java schema object
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JAVA", line 182
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

Comment: This works but I am writing a tool to retrieve the java code in a database and I cannot force users to be sysdba. It also seems to work if you login as the user that owns the object.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, but after a few searches on google I solve it. Probably will help someone.

```
DECLARE 
 b CLOB;
 c varchar2(2000);
 i integer:= 255;
begin
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(b, false);
  DBMS_JAVA.export_resource('<object_name>', '<schema_name>', b);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('java_resource:');
  DBMS_LOB.read(b, i, 1, c);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c);
end;
```