# Get java class content from oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle, loadjava

Is it possible to get the java `.class` file from a database?
I mean java classes, which was loaded via `loadjava` tool with `-r -s -v -g` parameters.

How to do this?

**Edit:**
I need it in readable form ;)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`DBMS_JAVA` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/appendixa.htm).
With `DBMS_JAVA` you can export both `.java` and `.class` files, using:

- `export_source` - to export `.java` file

  ```
  PROCEDURE export_source(name VARCHAR2, schema VARCHAR2, blob BLOB)
  PROCEDURE export_source(name VARCHAR2, blob BLOB)
  PROCEDURE export_source(name VARCHAR2, clob CLOB)
  ```
- `export_class` - to export `.class` file

  ```
  PROCEDURE export_class(name VARCHAR2, schema VARCHAR2, blob BLOB)
  PROCEDURE export_class(name VARCHAR2, blob BLOB)
  ```

[Here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/guide8i/ch09_07.htm) you can find some examples on how to use that to read the source of `.java` files.

Comment: Unfortunetely, it returns `java.sql.SQLException: no such java schema object` (with `export_source`). When I used `export_class` blob contains chain of letters and numbers.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471501/trying-to-export-java-source-code-from-an-oracle-database)

Comment: I saw this. I'm afraid that I can use `export_class` because I'm loading whole .jar via loadjava, and there are compiled `.class' files in it. So the problem is that, of course, `export_class` returns a class, but in unrecognizable form. And when I save this blob (returned by `export`) as `.class` file, it's unrecognizable for JVM too

Comment: but +1 for you, finall I get something from export - I did not indicated that I need it in readable form ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if it's a lil bit too late, but I've recently struggled with the same problem and maybe it can help someone.

First of all, if you have grant to load javaclass code via export_class, than all you need after you've exported it is to decompile it with javap.exe. You need to open cmd.exe (if you work on Windows), print there path to javap.exe on your computer, than after space "-c -s -verbose" and than after another space path to the *class file you've created. Something like that:

```
C:\Programm Files\Java\JDK\bin\javap.exe -c -s -verbose C:\Exports\file.class
```

You will have decompiled bytecode. It's readable, although you need to know JVM instructions.

Secondly, if you don't have grant to read it and by some reasons you don't want to get it, you can extract javaclass code another way. All javaclass codes are stored in the table sys.idl_ub1$ in long raw format. So you get the code like that:

```
select a.obj#,a.code,b.name
  from sys.idl_ub1$ a 
 inner join sys.obj$ b on a.obj#=b.obj#
                      and b.name = 'Name of your class'
```

You open the code in text editor and save it. Unfortunately you can't just decompile it right after this, cause code in this table helds some extra data at the beginning, and javap.exe will give an error. So you should open it in notepad and try to delete symbols at the beginning until java.exe will be able to decompile it. In my case I have to look at symbols like that:

```
Êþº¾
```

and to delete all data before them. But I'm not sure whether it will work for all cases. 
And after that you will get decompiled bytecode. :)

Comment: know this is old. Sorry for resurecting. The code column is gone as of 12c. There is a piece column in its place with the long raw and I assume its equivalent. This hex string will contain CAFEBABE which is the hex equivalent of Êþº¾. It is the start of all java classes. Seems oracle wraps the java classes in its own code somehow before saving in idl_ub1 table. But when I try to compile it it fails due to extra characters at the end of the class file. Any idea if we need to remove characters at the end of the class as well? Also I need to convert from HEX to ascii to get a valid class file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after a few searches on google I solve it. Probably will help someone. Just an exemple

```
DECLARE 
 b CLOB;
 c varchar2(2000);
 i integer:= 255;
begin
  DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(b, false);
  DBMS_JAVA.export_resource('<object_name>', '<schema_name>', b);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('java_resource:');
  DBMS_LOB.read(b, i, 1, c);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c);
end;
```