# Can we delete records from Meta Dictionary

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to re-compile one of the .Java file in Oracle 11g and I am getting the below error:

```
$ . /dboracle/orabase/product/11.2.0.BTSP8/bin/loadjava -verbose -resolve -synonym -user nm/nm -grant PUBLIC DeviceAttribParserConstants.java
arguments: '-user' 'nm/***' '-verbose' '-resolve' '-synonym' '-grant' 'PUBLIC' ' DeviceAttribParserConstants.java'
creating : source com/bt/nmsloader/model/DeviceAttribParserConstants
loading  : source com/bt/nmsloader/model/DeviceAttribParserConstants
Error while creating source com/bt/nmsloader/model/DeviceAttribParserConstants
    ORA-29542: class com/bt/nmsloader/model/DeviceAttribParserConstants already defined by source DeviceAttribParserConstants/java
ORA-06512: at line 1

The following operations failed
    source com/bt/nmsloader/model/DeviceAttribParserConstants: creation (createFailed)
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```

When I have looked in the ALL_Objects meta-dictionary I did not found JAVA SOURCE but can only see JAVA CLASS for DeviceAttribParserConstants.

Now when I am trying to recompile then I am getting above error and if I am dropping the same JAVA class file then I am getting error as below:

```
ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly. 
ORA-06512: at line1
* Cause: An attempt was made to create or drop JAVA class or resources that is a known result from compilation of an existing JAVA Source object.
```

Can someone help me in resolving this error.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't help, but I can comment :). You said: "Can we delete records from Meta Dictionary?" My answer: if you want to destroy your database, go ahead. Otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we delete records from Meta Dictionary

You shouldn't as it is likely to corrupt your database.

> Now when I am trying to recompile then I am getting above error and if I am dropping the same JAVA class file then I am getting error as below:
>
> ```
> ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly. 
> ORA-06512: at line1
> * Cause: An attempt was made to create or drop JAVA class or resources that is a known result from compilation of an existing JAVA Source object.
> ```

The [`loadjava` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html#GUID-B80B4492-55BB-4B75-919C-6E5962380710) has a `force` option:

```
-force      Forces files to be loaded, even if they match digest table entries.
```

So you can try:

```
loadjava -verbose -force -resolve -synonym -user nm/nm -grant PUBLIC DeviceAttribParserConstants.java
```

You can also try to [drop the existing java object](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8020.htm#SQLRF01521):

```
SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  OWNER = 'NM'
AND    OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%DeviceAttribParserConstants';

DROP JAVA CLASS NM.<insert_object_name>
```

and then try using `loadjava` without the force option.

*(You may want to try [backing up the existing class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965436/get-java-class-content-from-oracle-database) before you drop/overwrite it just in case you need to revert to the prior version.)*

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @MTO ... it helped me to resolve this :-)